# Swiping A View with Gestures

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I am trying to develop an application to Iphone; but i am new-bee so i have got a lot of problems.

My application has got a default view and another small view in the main view that name is flashcard.

I want to add capability this view swiping (or sliding) like Photos in Iphone. For example if user swipes view until the inner view's center reaches bounds of main view there will be two possibilities,
1- if user finish swiping before reach inner view will return to original position.
2- if user don't stop swiping, inner view will go out at screen from swipe direction and return the screen from the opposite direction.

So i declare UIPanGestureRecognizer at viewDidLoad like below

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panFlashCard = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanFlashCard:)];

[flashcard addGestureRecognizer:panFlashCard];
[panFlashCard release];
```

handPanFlashCard action:

```
UIView *piece = [recognizer view];
    CGPoint center = piece.center;
    CGFloat x = 160; // the original x axis of inner view

    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:piece ];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.55];
        [piece setCenter:CGPointMake(piece.center.x + translation.x, center.y)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        CGFloat totalX;
        totalX= x + translation.x;
        if(translation.x <0)
        {            
            if (totalX <= 0)
            {
                [self showNextCard];
            }
            else
            {
                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.55];
                           [piece setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, center.y)];
                           [UIView commitAnimations];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (totalX >= self.view.bounds.size.width)
            {
                [self showPreviousCard];
            }
            else
            {
                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.55];
                [piece setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, center.y)];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
            }
        }
    }
```

showNextCard action:

```
[flashcard setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width + flashcard.bounds.size.width, flashcard.center.y)]; 

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.55];
    [flashcard setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, flashcard.center.y)]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

showPreviousCard action:

```
  [flashcard setCenter:CGPointMake(0 - flashcard.bounds.size.width, flashcard.center.y)]; 

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.55];
    [flashcard setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, flashcard.center.y)]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

When i run this application, it builds and runs successfully but there is something wrong with animations, some frame mistakes i think.

Please help me to correct this code and run fluent animations while swiping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do then you can just use built in controls for this. Take a look at the pagingEnabled property on the UIScrollView class. There is also a sample project called PhotoScroller that may help.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I will look the sample code; but i am not sure these controls suit for me. Because i want to add some labels on inner view and fetch new datas from sqlite database every full swipe (NextCard or PreviousCard action)

Comment: You can add whatever views you want to a scroll view. So you can have your array of cards with each card being a UIView holding multiple labels. Then you just have to figure out which card is getting shown and do your loading.